# Bug in JSON decode from API Wunderground

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have code where I get weather forecast data from the Wunderground API. The problem is that I put the script on the website yesterday and since then it has been displayed constantly the same, even though the data in the JSON file from Wudnerground is already updated when I view this file.

Something is wrong, but I don't know what... Below is my php code.

```
$json= file_get_contents('https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/5day?geocode=51.42,17.26&format=json&units=m&language=pl-PL&apiKey=MY API KEY');

$data = json_decode($json);
$day = $data->dayOfWeek;

$maxTemp = $data->temperatureMax;
$minTemp = $data->temperatureMin;
$icon = $data->daypart[0]->iconCode;
$deszcz = $data->daypart[0]->precipChance;
$windDir = $data->daypart[0]->windDirectionCardinal;
$windSpeed = $data->daypart[0]->windSpeed;
$UV = $data->daypart[0]->uvIndex;
$txt = $data->daypart[0]->wxPhraseLong;

echo "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#c9c9c9'>$day[1]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#c9c9c9'>$day[2]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#c9c9c9'>$day[3]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#c9c9c9'>$day[4]</span></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$icon[2]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$icon[4]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$icon[6]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$icon[8]</span></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$txt[2]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$txt[4]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$txt[6]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:10px; color:#c9c9c9'>$txt[8]</span></td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#d30000'>$maxTemp[1]°</span>     |     <span style='font-size:18px; color:#006dd3'>$minTemp[1]°</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#d30000'>$maxTemp[2]°</span>     |     <span style='font-size:18px; color:#006dd3'>$minTemp[2]°</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#d30000'>$maxTemp[3]°</span>     |     <span style='font-size:18px; color:#006dd3'>$minTemp[3]°</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:18px; color:#d30000'>$maxTemp[4]°</span>     |     <span style='font-size:18px; color:#006dd3'>$minTemp[4]°</span></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $deszcz[2]%</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $deszcz[4]%</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $deszcz[6]%</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $deszcz[8]%</span></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $windDir[2] $windSpeed[2] km/h</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$windDir[4] $windSpeed[4] km/h</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$windDir[6] $windSpeed[6] km/h</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$windDir[8] $windSpeed[8] km/h</span></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'><i class='wi wi-raindrop' title='Opad szansa'></i> $UV[2]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$UV[4]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$UV[6]</span></td><td style='padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 25%'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#c9c9c9'>$UV[8]</span></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: "Something is wrong" - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: The data that is displayed is "old", although the data in the file that I download is updated.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Sounds like this isn't a JSON problem after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents will cache the result.

This should solve it:

```php
$opts = [
  'http' => [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Cache-Control: no-cache',
  ],
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/5day?geocode=51.42,17.26&format=json&units=m&language=pl-PL&apiKey=MY API KEY', false, $context);
```

But you could also fetch the data from the php using curl - wich is probably how I would do it.

```
$url = 'https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/5day?geocode=51.42,17.26&format=json&units=m&language=pl-PL&apiKey=MY API KEY';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cache-Control: no-cache'));

$json = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch)) {
  echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I have inserted as below, but still the data is the same as before. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in Curl.

$opts = [
    'http' => [
      'method' => 'GET',
      'header' => 'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    ],
];
  
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
  
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/5day?geocode=51.42,17.26&format=json&units=m&language=pl-PL&apiKey=API KEY', false, $context);


$data = json_decode($json);

Comment: Added the curl option - but it's impossible for me to validate if it's correct and if the data loaded from the api is correct without a key. 

How are you validating that the json files content is changed?

Comment: Curl are works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely a PHP problem, but something upstream. Either the data provider is giving you wonky data, or there is an improperly-configured or otherwise misbehaving intermediate proxy between you and wunderground that is causing it. You need to inspect the HTTP response headers, and `file_get_contents()` simply won't accommodate this.

Personally, I would switch to Guzzle and/or curl, but you can shimmy your way around it with `fopen()` and `stream_get_meta_data()`:

```php
$url = 'https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/5day?geocode=51.42,17.26&format=json&units=m&language=pl-PL&apiKey=MY API KEY';

$fh = fopen($url, 'r');
$json = stream_get_contents($fh);
$headers = stream_get_meta_data($fh);
```

The headers will tell you the date the information was generated, the cache lifetime, and give you a trace token that might be useful to tracking down the issue on the provider's side. The headers may also contain evidence of a caching proxy causing problems in the middle.

That said, I generally don't recommend making API requests against 3rd parties for every single request to your site, as it's likely that you will be making a *lot* of identical requests and either burning through your request allocations, or the goodwill of the provider. Implement caching in your app.